# Is it possible to mock an authenticated Firebase user, in order to run full testing with jest, while preserving the database rules?

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, testing, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs

I have a Firebase Realtime Database set up with a bunch of basic rules revolving around basic user authentication:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      "$user_id" : {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
       }
    }
  }
}
```

These rules depend on the `auth.uid` built-in Firebase variable, which is accessible during development/production as a user is logged in with any given provider.

However, when I am running jest tests on a duplicated database with the same rules, I do not have access to this `auth.uid` since there is no actual user logged in.

Is there a way to solve this? A way to perhaps mock some sort of testing user on Firebase itself or through my client-side test code?

I would like the testing to run on a database that is as similar as possible to the regular database. I don't want to have a different rules structure on the test database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution I came up with which is more of a workaround is this:

1. Set up a test environment variable like `FIREBASE_TEST_UID`.
2. Reference this uid when running tests.
3. Manually change the rules comparing the `$user_id"` to `auth.uid` to the compare it with the actual stored `FIREBASE_TEST_UID`
4. Now the database is protected from reading and writing by public non "authenticated" users while the rules structure is left similar and the `FIREBASE_TEST_UID` is private (.gitignored env file).